# i m getting Error in in Repeater with in Repeater in Data Source

Tags: c#, asp.net, datasource

```
    <b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Hotel_FloorId")%></b> 
     <b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Hotel_FloorName")%></b>    


     <br>
    <asp:repeater id="childRepeater" runat="server" datasource='<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem).Row.GetChildRows ("myrelation") %>' >
        <itemtemplate>
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "[\"RoomDoorNo\"]")%><br>   
        </itemtemplate>
    </asp:Repeater> 

  </itemtemplate>
```

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string css = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(css);
    cnn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter cmd1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT *  FROM   HM_Hotel_Floor", cnn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    cmd1.Fill(ds, "Floors");
    parentRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables["Floors"];



    SqlDataAdapter cmd2 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from HM_Rooms", cnn);
    cmd2.Fill(ds, "Rooms");
    ds.Relations.Add("myrelation", ds.Tables["Floors"].Columns["Hotel_FloorId"], ds.Tables["Rooms"].Columns["Hotel_FloorId"]);
    Page.DataBind();



}
```

The Error is Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DataRowView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please Any one Help me

Comment: Add this namespace  `Using System.Data;`

Answer (score 0):

Code-behind (.cs) and  Page (.aspx) files have their own classes so they have separate imports too. In this case you are missing an import on top of your ASPX view:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
```

This is required because you are casting a Container.DataItem to DataRowView in the ASPX view.

In addition make sure you have the using statement in your code-behind file as well:

```
Using System.Data;
```